# perror and strerror with close(2) involved

Tags: c, system-calls, errno, unistd.h, strerror

I have this code with close(2) implemented, as many of you know(including myself) this closes the standard error, but what are the main repercussions of closing it?

And why is "main: Success" printed? Shouldn't every directory have the "." dir that can be opened?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>


int main() {
    close(2);
    if (fopen(".","r")) 
    {
        printf("main: %s \n", strerror(errno));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

On the other hand

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main() {
    close(2);
    if (fopen(".","r")) 
    {
        perror("main");
    }  
    return 0;
}
```

This doesn't print anything, any ideas why?

Comment: My guess is that both calls to `fopen` haves success, but since you have closed `stderr` you can not see the message in the second snippet (`perror` uses `stderr`), try `fprintf(stderr, "main: %s \n", strerror(errno));` in the first snippet and see what happens.

Comment: @DavidRanieri If stderr is closed, you can't print to stderr.

Comment: @Barmar No surprise anymore :) yes, that's the point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard error is where error messages are supposed to be printed. So `perror()` prints its error message on standard error. If you close standard error, it can't print the message.

> Why is "main: Success" printed? Shouldn't every directory have the "." dir that can be opened?

Yes, it does. You didn't get an error when calling `fopen()`, so `errno == 0`, and the message for this is `Success`.

If you want to print an error message when `fopen()` fails, you need to test for `NULL`:

```
if (fopen(".") == NULL) {
    printf("main: %s \n", strerror(errno));
}
```

Note that when opening files, the FD that's used is the lowest available FD. Since you've closed FD 2, that will most likely be used when opening `.`. So standard error now points to the `.` directory, which you can't write to, and `perror()` will get an error when it tries to write there. But it can't report this error (where would it report it?).

Answer (score 0):

> what are the main repercussions of closing it?

Undefined Behavior. The C standard says "The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances: [...] The value of a pointer to a FILE object is used after the associated file is closed", and [POSIX says](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stdin.html) "The stderr stream is expected to be open for reading and writing."